# Not able to create proper session's for User management application in php

Tags: php

I have created a user management application in PHP, Where Super Admin has a rights/permissions to grant and revoke permissions to the Users.

I have created Session for all the users including the Super Admin.

Below code for the same:

```
$_SESSION['User_login'] = $single_value['user_name'];//USER NAME
  $_SESSION['permission'] = $single_value['permission']; // Granted permissions
  $_SESSION['role_code'] = $single_value['role_id'];// ROLE CODE
```

The working is fine but I'm facing the problem in the below condition.

1. **Super Admin** has a right to create users with **Create_user.php** file and USER **Test** has a right to access the only **download_file.php**

When **User Test** Logins to the **download_file.php** file he is able to do all the tasks mentioned in that file but if Test user enters the **Create_user.php** in URL then he is able to view that file which belongs to Super Admin without any problem.

So I'm confused here how to stop this process when 1 user does not have the rights/permissions to open a particular file, the user should be directed to the home page or any error something.

Comment: I don't know the complexity may be. But, I feel like it's simple.. when any user login to the system SET the permissions info in the SESSION array & when user click on ```create_user.php``` just check in that page that, the user has sufficient require permission info available in his SESSION or not. If not then, redirect the user to Login page or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with the help of in_array() function.

Creating a sperate table for all the menu with the page name and checking the currently rendered page with the given/granted permissions to the logged in user.

menu table:
[image]

Below code for checking the permissions.

**CHECK.PHP**

```
function check($filename)
    {
            include_once('config.php');
        $sql = "SELECT name from menu where page_name = '".$filename."' ";
            #echo $sql;
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if($result->num_rows > 0 )
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {   
                    if(!in_array($row['name'],explode(",",$_SESSION['permission'])))
                    {
                        header('location:logout.php');
                    }
                    #echo "data = ".$row['name']; echo "<br> My permission = ".$_SESSION['permission'];
                }//EOF WHILE
            }//EOF IF       
            else
            {
                echo "0 result";
            }

    }//EOF CHECK();
```

calling this function where you want to check permissions

**Create_user.php**

```
    <?php include_once 'check.php';
   check(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); #passing the name of current file.
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Rest of the code -->
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of conditional check at the beginning of your `Create_user.php` file which check what permissions the user requesting that page has.  Something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['permission'] != 'Admin') {   // or however you name your permissions
    header('Location: /download_file.php'); // redirect non-admin users
}
// ... admin stuff follows
```